# Исключение из использования

Tags: употребление-слов

Насколько корректно данное словосочетание? Некоторые коллеги говорят "это как-то не по-русски", другие же воспринимают вполне нормально. Выражение используется в проектно-эксплуатационной документации (регламент, техническое задание, руководство пользователя и др.).

Comment: @Александр1001, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже кажется некорректным данное словосочетание. Исключение может быть из правил, из списка, из реестра, из перечня. В проектно-эксплуатационной документации тоже не встречала, сейчас вот посмотрела. Может, лучше сказать "исключение из списков..., используемых для..."

Answer (score 1):

Исключение из использование - это термин, обозначающий определенное понятие. Потребность в таком термине есть, но более приемлемое выражение найти не удалось (например, "вывод из эксплуатации"  не подходит).

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1) Открытое обращение пивоваров к Д. Медведеву. Необоснованное исключение ПЭТ-тары из использования на пивном рынке приведёт к серьезным экономическим последствиям

(2) Выявление и исключение из использования пиратских копий : Общие инструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я особых проблем не вижу. Понятно, что тот или иной продукт (материал) перестали использовать в том или ином контексте. А в технической документации "понятность" и "однозначность" являются, пожалуй, основными требованиями.
Впрочем, Вы можете написать "исключение из использ**уемых**". Переделка текста потребуется минимальная.

Answer (score 0):

В большом англо-русском словаре на Академике предлагается термин: снятие с эксплуатации -  выходящий из употребления; отживающий, исчезающий.